# After I update using .html(), the browser responds slower with respect to the number of new rows. Can you help me see my mistake?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance

I use the following code to send info to a PHP script and get the response and data using json_encode.
If the body of the table has few rows, it updates the HTML pretty quickly, but if the number of rows returned grows, the browser updates slower and slower and even more it responds slower and slower. It takes time to highlight the row of the table where the mouse pointer is.
can you help me see where I am doing wrong and explain it to me so I won't do the mistake in the future?

```
 $.ajax({
      url: '../scripts_php/rapoarte_standard.php',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      async: true,
      data: {
        actiune: 'genereazaListaBaterii',
        dataStart: dataStart,
        dataFinal: dataFinal,
        cuvinte: cuvinte,
        idScopComanda: idScopComanda,
        idElDif: idElDif,
        idStandard: idStandard
      },
      beforeSend: function() {
        //alert('Se trimite'); //ceea ce se executa inainte sa trimita informatia si pana ce revine un raspuns
        $('#listaBaterii').html('');
        $('#listaBaterii').remove();
        $('#divSpatiuDeLucru').append(
          '<div id="listaBaterii" class="w-100"></div>'
        );
        loader('#listaBaterii');
      },
      success: function(data) {
        console.clear();
        console.log(data);
        console.log(Date($.now()) + ' : Inainte de update html()');
        var divTabel = $('#listaBaterii'),
          sirBaterii = data.tabelTbody,
          tbody = '',
          l = sirBaterii.length;
        divTabel.html(data.tabelBaterii);
        console.log(Date($.now()) + ' : Dupa update divTabel.html()');
        for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
          tbody += sirBaterii[i];
        }
        console.log(Date($.now()) + ' : Dupa creare tbody pt tbodyTabel');
        var tbodyTabel = $('#tabelBateriiGasite tbody');
        tbodyTabel.html(tbody);
        console.log(Date($.now()) + ' : Dupa update tbodyTabel.html()');
        //createTable('#tabelBateriiGasite');
      },
      error: function(data) {
        alert('Eroare!' + '\r\n' + 'Verifica console.log pentru detalii!');
        console.clear();
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
```

Comment: Building DOM elements with JS using strings is slow by the nature. Use proper DOM manipulating methods instead, and bring the data as text content rather than as DOMStrings.

Comment: @Teemu I have no experience in DOM manipulation. Can you give me a hint? What to use or what to learn for that?
Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @BalajOvidiu up to how many rows do you start to find that it is slow?  Is it in the range of 300 or 500 or?

Comment: @nopole for 42 rows, it takes around 9 seconds to update. for 68 rows it takes 48 seconds. Ty for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said in the comment that if it is 42 rows, it is taking 9 seconds. You said 68 rows and it is taking 48 seconds. So can you try if it is 84 rows... is it taking 81 seconds? If so, it looks like you are doing something that is O(n²) and you can debug into what you are doing that is  O(n²). The code you provided doesn't look like  it has this O(n²) operation. Are you pasting everything or with some code omitted?  You can also try updating the table with static strings and see if it is taking that long.

Try

```
tbody += `<tr><td>${i}</td></tr>`;
```

and see how fast it is. By the way, I don't see the `<tr>` and `<td>` in your code.

In the following I can update 3000 rows and it took about 1 to 2 seconds:

(I even make the string add up `<tr>` and `</tr>` separately to "make it slower".)

The code starts a visual timer on screen, so you can see it running, and then after 1 second, the table is updated. You don't have to wait for that 1 second. It is merely to show the timer running, and then let the "pause" be seen when the table is updated for the 3000 rows:

```js
let elTimer = document.querySelector("#timer");

setInterval(function() {
  elTimer.innerText = (new Date()).getTime();
}, 33);

let elTable = document.querySelector("#my-data"),
  s = "";

setTimeout(function() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 3000; i++) {
    s += "<tr>";
    s += `<td>${i}</td><td>${Math.random()}</td><td>${Array.from({length:9}).map(e => String.fromCharCode(97 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 26))).join("")}</td>`;
    s += "</tr>";
  }
  elTable.innerHTML = s;

}, 1000);
```

```css
#my-data {
  border-collapse: collapse
}

#my-data td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: .2em 1.2em
}
```

```html
<div id="timer"></div>

<table id="my-data"></table>
```

But one technique is not to add up a long string, but use a short string for each row and add to the table each time:

```js
let elTimer = document.querySelector("#timer");

setInterval(function() {
  elTimer.innerText = (new Date()).getTime();
}, 33);

let elTable = document.querySelector("#my-data");

setTimeout(function() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 3000; i++) {
    let elTR = document.createElement("tr");
    let s = `<td>${i}</td><td>${Math.random()}</td><td>${Array.from({length:9}).map(e => String.fromCharCode(97 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 26))).join("")}</td>`;
    elTR.innerHTML = s;
    elTable.appendChild(elTR);
  }

}, 1000);
```

```css
#my-data {
  border-collapse: collapse
}

#my-data td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: .2em 1.2em
}
```

```html
<div id="timer"></div>

<table id="my-data"></table>
```

No matter how fast you make your code works, there might be a point when your code starts to run slow, depending on what operations you are doing. So in this case, you can use one general technique: async functions. With that, you can tell it to "sleep a while" whenever you want it to. The code below let the function sleep until the next cycle, for every 30 rows it updates. If you want, you can make it 10 or even smaller. It will update the table for the first `N` row, and visible on screen, and then will not hog the CPU, and then the next cycle, it will update the table for the next `N` rows. That's why you can see the timer running smoothly and never have a pause:

```js
let elTimer = document.querySelector("#timer");

setInterval(function() {
  elTimer.innerText = (new Date()).getTime();
}, 33);

let elTable = document.querySelector("#my-data");

function sleepAWhile(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}

setTimeout(async function() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 3000; i++) {
    let elTR = document.createElement("tr");
    let s = `<td>${i}</td><td>${Math.random()}</td><td>${Array.from({length:9}).map(e => String.fromCharCode(97 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 26))).join("")}</td>`;
    elTR.innerHTML = s;
    elTable.appendChild(elTR);
    if (i % 30) await sleepAWhile(0);
  }

}, 1000);
```

```css
#my-data {
  border-collapse: collapse
}

#my-data td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: .2em 1.2em;
  width: 5ch;
}

#my-data td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 21ch;
}

#my-data td:last-child {
  width: 11ch;
}
```

```html
<div id="timer"></div>

<table id="my-data"></table>
```

Comment: from the php script I return an array with the entire <tr></tr> already created in the script. From what you described should I understand that is better to return only values and create each <td></td>, <tr></tr> and the body in the success function? Could the problem be generated by the fact I return an array of rows instead to return a bi-dimensional array with values and create the html dynamically? Again, ty for your reply & answer.

Comment: usually, we don't reply with `<tr>` and `<td>` but should return data. But even if you return them as `<tr><td>`, that shouldn't make it so slow.  I suggest (1) you update the table with static data and see if `n` is 48 or `100` or `200`, whether it makes your program so slow. and (2) console.log() each line you are adding to `tbody` to see if there are something weird that is causing the O(n²) situation

Comment: Dear nopole I can't understand some things here, but I sent an array with info from the php script back to the $.ajax and I built the <tbody> of <table> by creating each <tr><td></td>....</tr> and appending it to the <tbdody></tbody> in the success function and it works perfectly. Now it took 1s to append 267 new rows. You and @Teemu were right! Is a lesson learned for me. Ty you for helping me on this topic! Best of all to you!

Comment: so could you be adding multiple `<tbody>` to the same table again and again? If you send back correct `<tr><td>...` it shouldn't make the code so slow. It may seem like something was being done for stacking up more and more data and that's why it is O(n²) .  So right now 1 second is acceptable to your program?

Comment: at this moment, creating the <tr><td></td>...</tr> dynamically and appeding it to the <tbody></tbody> inside the success function makes it append 277 new rows in around 1 second, and it is more then perfect for me. It takes another 24seconds to transform the table using dataTable() but this is not a must. Thank you again for your help!